# most common file type to html converter

Tags: file, types, document, converters

Is there a plugin(for example joomla plugin) or program which converts most known file type(.chm, .doc, .pdf etc..) to html. After conversion I want to search any item in that text.

PS: I know that there are some programs pdftodoc, doctohtml.. But I need a whole program or portal which converts all generic file types to html and in that portal there must be a search properties.

Thanks.

Comment: This question isn't really programing related and should probably be moved to superuser or something.